# Python: Nesting Dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

So I need to nest some dictionaries in python.

The dictionary code I have so far is this:

```
dict[counter] = {'title': title, 'year': year}
```

So, this adds to the dictionary `dict` a key with the value of the variable `counter`. The value for this key is another dictionary. Here, year and title are variables.

But when I prettyprint this, it looks like this:

```
302: {'title': u"You Won't See Me", 'year': u'1965'},
```

(That was just a sample of the output).
It seems to have interpreted it as a string.

The way I understood it, if Python had recognized it as a dictionary, prettyprint would have indented/newlined it.

Right?

So I guess the real question is, is this a valid way to add nested dictionaries?

PS The code that I used for the prettyprinter is this:

```
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(depth=1000)
pp.pprint(dict)
```

Just in case that's relevant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how nested dicts are pretty printed; it's definitely the case that nested dicts aren't interpreted as strings.

To convince yourself, print out

```
dict[key][nested_key]
```

If the nested dict had been interpreted/stored as string, that would yield an error.

Also: `dict` is a discouraged name for dicts because `dict` refers to the type object.

Comment: So when I ran that, it came up with a KeyError. However, it did print the value. It looked like this: `KeyError: u"You've Really Got a Hold on Me"`. So the value printed in the error message...

Comment: that long string is what you used as a dict key?!

Comment: No...the key is `'title'`. "You've Really Got a Hold on Me" is the song's title -- the value for that key.

Comment: how about `dict[302]['title']`?

Comment: @evamvid The `KeyError` is raised if you supply a key that does not exist, and it will show you the key you tried.  Therefore, you must have given the key `u"You've Really Got a Hold on Me"`.  Did you accidentally do `dict[302][title]`?  That is why Erik suggested you do `dict[302]['title']`.

Comment: @SethMMorton Yeah, that's what I did.....it wasn't acident =) I didn't realize to put the key in quotes.

Comment: @evamvid Yeah, that can be confusing if you are used to Perl (I'm assuming you have a Perl background here)

Comment: @SethMMorton Actually no; I just haven't done much with Python dictionaries before =)

Comment: Dictionaries are virtually the same in all languages, by the way; just for the record.

Comment: @ErikAllik True, but in Perl you don't have to put quotes around the keys when passing a string directly... it assumes you want them quoted and does that for you in the background.  It can do this because variables in Perl have to begin with a `$`.  In Python you have to quote the keys if you are giving a string and not a variable, because there is no way to tell the intent like there is in Perl.  So, while the basics of dictionaries are the same in all languages, the details can be different.

Comment: Yes.  I had assumed that your comment that dictionaries are the same in all languages was directed at me because I had thought the OP had a Perl background because they left off the quotes in the dictionary key.  My comment in response was explaining why I had made that assumption, which is the different in syntax between Perl and Python that can trip up a programmer (as it did to me when I switched from Perl to Python).  I think we are on the same page here, I'm just saying that when dealing with multiple languages, syntax differences can be important.

Answer (score 1):

The `pprint` module indents *as needed*; objects that fit on one line are not expanded. You've been adding nested dictionaries *just fine*.

If the dictionary has more keys and values, more lines are used as needed:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint({'foo': 'bar', 'spam': {'ham': 'eggs'}})
{'foo': 'bar', 'spam': {'ham': 'eggs'}}
>>> pprint.pprint({'foo': 'bar', 'spam': {'ham': 'eggs'}, 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious': 'superformiweldigeindefantakolosachtig'})
{'foo': 'bar',
 'spam': {'ham': 'eggs'},
 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious': 'superformiweldigeindefantakolosachtig'}
>>> pprint.pprint({'foo': 'bar', 'spam': {'ham': 'eggs', 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious': 'superformiweldigeindefantakolosachtig'}})
{'foo': 'bar',
 'spam': {'ham': 'eggs',
          'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious': 'superformiweldigeindefantakolosachtig'}}
```

At no point does Python turn your nested dictionary into a string; if it *did*, `pprint` would have put *quotes* around the string object, just like the strings used as keys in your dictionary!